# Index of items in a checkedlistbox using c# in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 10 items in a checkedlist box. I believe that the index of the 1st element is 0, index of 2nd element is 1 and so on until index 9.My requirement is to find the true index of the elements as they occur in the list when i check them.Presently i'm using the following code but its not producing desired result. For example when i check the very 1st element no ,message is shown.When i check the 2nd element, the message says index 0 is checked.When i check the 10th element it says index 1 is checked....Whats wrong with my code?Please advice.

```
   private void clbAnnually_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int indexChecked in clbAnnually.CheckedIndices)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() + ", is checked");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not really. I just want to know the true index of the currently checked element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve it is a bit tricky, this is because the `Item` will be checked *after* the `ItemCheck` event. Hence, you actually got to check if your current `SelectedIndex` during the `ItemCheck` event is *not* among the `CheckedIndices` to show that it *currently* is the one checked:

```
private void clbAnnually_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {           
    if (!checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Contains(clbAnnually.SelectedIndex))
        MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + ", is checked");
}
```

Comment: PERFECT answer.Thank you @Ian.You saved my day.

Comment: @gomeshmunda glad to help. :)