# Show ValueMember of a CheckedListBox in c#

Tags: c#

I have a CheckedListBox which is bound to a table.I am wanting to get the ValueMember of any item from the list which i check.Presently i am running a loop through all the checked items of the list to show the ValueMember, as a result this shows me several messageboxes which i don't want. I want, at any instance if i check any item then it should show me its corrresponding  ValueMember.My current code is

```
foreach (DataRowView view in clbAnnually.CheckedItems)
{
  MessageBox.Show(view[clbAnnually.ValueMember].ToString());
}
```

I have looked for similar question in SO, but they didn't solve my problem. Please advice possibly with code.

Comment: Did the answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313328/index-of-items-in-a-checkedlistbox-using-c-sharp-in-winforms not help in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CheckedListBox.ItemCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. It's raised when a user checks an item and provides all information about the checked item.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Name");

table.Rows.Add(0, "Name 0");
table.Rows.Add(1, "Name 1");
table.Rows.Add(2, "Name 2");

checkedListBox1.DataSource = table;
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck;
```

1.

```
private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
    CheckedListBox clb = (CheckedListBox)sender;
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)clb.Items[e.Index];
    MessageBox.Show(row[clb.ValueMember].ToString());
}
```

2.

```
private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
    CheckedListBox clb = (CheckedListBox)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(clb.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Yes Sir, I have used the above mentioned foreach loop inside ItemCheck event.But my present code gives me a series of messages which i don,t want.

Comment: Why are you looping through all checked items? Why don't use parameters you are getting in the "e" event argument?

Comment: Are you using DataTable as your data source?

Comment: No DataTable. I am using DataSet and DataAdapters to bind my CLB

Comment: @gomeshmunda Then you are using a DataTable.

Comment: Thanks @Gosha.In the ItemCheck event MessageBox.Show(clbAnnually.SelectedValue.ToString());                              also seems to work